# Why is there a 'TypeError' here?

Tags: python, time, typeerror

I was building a quick 1-hour game, got about half of the way through, and the `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` error occurred.  I have no clue why this occurred, there seems to be some problem with using `time.sleep[x]` function.  My full error and the code are below.

Code:

```
import time
import random

def intro():
    print("You are playing a game...")
    time.sleep[3]
    print("of chance.")
    time.sleep[1.5]
    print("Enter [1] to continue.")
    introChoice=''
    while introChoice not in ['1']:
          introChoice=input("> ")
    if introChoice=="1":
          tutorial()
```

Error:

```
You are playing a game...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacob/Documents/a game of chance.py", line 126, in <module>
    intro()
  File "/Users/jacob/Documents/a game of chance.py", line 9, in intro
    time.sleep[3]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help is appreciated, and I'm willing to give more information if necessary.

Comment: `time.sleep[3]` is not a list. . make it as `time.sleep(3)`. Similarly apply this to others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sleep` is a function/method and not an indexable object. You call it like such:

```
sleep(time)
```

Not like:

```
sleep[time]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm such a noob at programming.

Comment: @dudens97 we all have to learn somehow and Stack Overflow is great environment for it. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the Python syntax for two very different things. `[]` is an indexing notation; `myindexable[i]` refers to the `i`th item in `myindexable`. `()`, meanwhile, is the notation for calling a function; `myfunc(n)` calls the function `myfunc` with the argument `n`.